# Combining multiple spring applications into one

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have developed 3 Web applications all of which should be separate because they serve very different purposes. I'm using LDAP authentication in each application to log in and based on LDAP group I assign users a Role. This role determines the access that users have within the web applications. I would like to be able to log in to one application and be able to access all of the applications with the correct user permissions. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use single signon frameworks like CAS. You can have can have a central server which will authenticate the user and redirect him to the application the user is trying to access. The authentication server will write a cookie after authentication, which will be used to auto login the user to other applications.